# How to convert any String into valid JSON format in JAVA

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am getting the String in following format which is causing problem while parsing using Jackson ObjectMapper readTree api. Code used to parse the given String is

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);
objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER, true);
objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS, true);
objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS, true);
JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(inputString);
```

It is throwing exception when it encounters "7" in the below String

```
{
OBJECT_CONVERSION_ERROR:"Failed..."
Portal:{
   7061:"User is....."}
}
```

How to convert such a String in Valid JSON format using JAVA ?
I am using jackson-all-1.9.11.jar

Below is my exception message

org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('7' (code 55)): was expecting either valid name character (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for quoted) to start field name
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@3fb1549b; line: 1, column: 1433]

Is there any way to convert the input String in valid json format before passing it to Object Mapper for parsing it ?

Comment: Can  you upload the code excerpt that throws the error? It's impossible to tell what's going on without seeing at least some code.

Comment: That looks like a javascript object, not valid JSON...

Comment: If the value shown is your input string, then this is not valid JSON since the name in name - value pairs should be strings, not numbers like 7061.

Comment: @RobObdeijn yes it is not a valid JSON format will it be possible to convert it into valid JSON format that is what my question is.

Answer (score 0):

The Jackson ObjectMapper expects double-quoted field names in its default configuration.

To change this behavior you could do the following:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); JSONObject json = (JSONObject) 
parser.parse(stringToParse);
```

Read more: http://www.java67.com/2016/10/3-ways-to-convert-string-to-json-object-in-java.html#ixzz4y2fACQlg